# Unable to get build definitions from server, returns empty

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

Had some issues using TfsConfigurationServer, getting build definitions per project name from visual studio online returns nothing.

Heres a summary of the code:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
server = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri(connection), tfsCred); 


TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsProjectCollection = server.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionID);
var buildServer = tfsProjectCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
var temp = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(projectName).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
return temp;
```

My other functions with getting project names works, however this one doesnt.

heres what the soap send and return. Seems like the endpoint invalidates the call.

[image]

Any ideas to how to make this work? (I suppose trying other methods, but kinda dodgy way, as the package should support tfs 2015 and visual studio online)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://vsoservername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"));
        IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
        var buildDefinitions = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("ProjectName");
        foreach (var buildDefinition in buildDefinitions)
        {
            string buildDefinitionName = buildDefinition.Name;
        }
```